# first and last token in a string in dos

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file, arguments

I need first and last token in a string
I am trying as below

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('type c.txt') do (
  set line=%%f
  set first=ini
  set last=ini
  call :processToken
  )
  goto :eof

:processToken
  echo func-%line%
  for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ("%line%") do (
rem   echo Got one token: %%a
  set first=%%a
  set last=%%a
  set line=%%b
  )
  if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
  goto :eof
```

But i see some weird behavior

my c.txt contains

```
name -p 11000 -m 11001 -dnN envvarfile variables -L     5388
```

What could be wrong in above script ?

Comment: _But i see some weird behavior_ - And do you can tell us what is weird?

Comment: Even though after updating the variable value, when printing it, i see wrong values.
Got to know it is because of not adding "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION"